# For every $0\leq \mu \leq 4$, there exists at most one attracting periodic orbit for function $F_\mu(x)= \mu x(1-x)$

Tags: dynamical-systems

How can I show that for every $0\leq \mu \leq 4$, there exists at most one attracting periodic orbit for function $F_\mu(x)= \mu x(1-x)?$